# Spring Boot DevTools not initialized because of the URLClassLoader with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application using Spring Platfrom 1.3.3.RELEASE.

In my development environment, I'm starting it in IntelliJ IDEA 15 as the "Spring Boot Application" type run configuration. Recently, I've added the 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools' for for class reloading as noted on the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html.

It worked at first, but recently I noticed that the class reloading from IDEA stopped working.

After some debugging, I found that the LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration is annotated with @ConditionalOnInitializedRestarter, which fails here
`return ConditionOutcome.noMatch("Restarter initialized without URLs");`.

The URLs are empty, because the `DefaultRestartInitializer` which initializes the URLs has following condition:
`return thread.getName().equals("main") && thread.getContextClassLoader()
                .getClass().getName().contains("AppClassLoader");`

Unfortunately, the `thread.getContextClassLoader().getClass().getName()` returns the `URLClassLoader` for me, and not the `AppClassLoader`.

Now, I'm not sure what could be wrong and how is the reloader supposed to work. Is my application/IDE using wrong class loader? Or is there bug in Spring?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the reason for the "wrong" classloader.

It's the "dynamic classpath" feature in IntelliJ IDEA:

`<property name="dynamic.classpath" value="true" />`

If it's disabled, the Reloader is initialized correctly.

Comment: What are the proper URLs that restarter should have?  mine is empty (and restart doesn't commence).

 Starting application xx.demo.starter.StarterApplication with URLs []